# Google - Are you sure you want to leave this webpage? null

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, google-search

I have recently been getting this message a lot on Google. It happens when I leave the page, click on a link or perform a search. It seems to go away after I click it and wont popup for a while but it keeps coming back. I attached a screenshot of the message. I am using internet explorer 11 (latest) on windows 8.1. Any help is appreciated.
[image: Why is google doing this?!]

Comment: Do other browsers do this too?

Comment: This prompt appears when you have typed something into an input box on the page, eg start typing an answer on this page and you will see it if you try to close; clear the answer box and it will close immediately. It is to some degree under the web-site's control (eg starting to type a comment will not cause the prompt).

Comment: @TimmyJim - Other browsers make a similar prompt, but with their own text and formatting.

Comment: @AFH I believe he was asking if the same popup happened in other browsers (eg. Firefox/google chrome) on my computer. I really only use internet explorer so idk if I can test with Firefox. I would like to know if anyone else is getting this popup as well, or if its just me.

Comment: @JCTechie - He was asking that, and I have told you what causes the prompt in IE. Since you weren't interested in other browsers, I thought I would answer his question in passing.

Comment: Check in private browsing also.

Comment: @vembutech ok I might try that

Comment: @AFH I understand, however the prompt is in error, it says null, and will happen without any text input (You can kind-of see that the google search is empty, I just went to the page and tried to close it.)

Comment: I guess it's a quirk of the Google site, maybe as the result of an IE limitation, or of a configuration setting or add-on which stops a script running.

Comment: @AFH - Google supports IE11.  Additonally, the author says, it also happens on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @Ramhound - The original question makes no reference to Chrome nor Firefox, and one of his comments specifically excludes them. Google may well support IE, but I've had lots of errors reporting `null` in IE, mostly as a result of script problems: I was never able to find out why I didn't get them in other browsers, but I put it down to either a limitation on IE's scripting engine or possibly a configuration option.

Comment: @AFH "Other browsers make a similar prompt, but with their own text and formatting." - indicates other browsers other then IE do the samething.

Comment: @Ramhound - Indeed so, and it was a response to JCTechie's comment, which I made, not the author. I haven't been able to reproduce the problem on IE11/Win10, but I can't access `google.com` (assuming that was where the symptoms appeared), as in the UK we are always redirected to `google.co.uk`.

Comment: in chrome or FF at least, you can use the developer console to try and track down any calls to `onBeforeunload` event or look for injected javascript. Also, try clearing your internet cache. If a programmer hooks onto onbeforeupload and returns null, it will trhow a dialog with the word null similar to what you have, so either google has a bug, or there is some other script running with a bug in it.

Comment: @Yorik If it were a script/plugin error, would it also show up on other websites? All I have is adblock and java, which neither have ever given me any issues.

Comment: Also @AFH You said your also getting null errors? maybe I should make a bug report to google?

Comment: My errors were flagged as scripting errors involving null pointers, which usually means uninitialised variables. Since I had no similar problems with other browsers, I abandoned IE and settled on Firefox, which has its own problems, of course, but I've learned to live with them. Occasionally I have to resort to IE when Firefox doesn't handle web-sites correctly, though this may be due to my add-ons. So it has been some time since I last saw this type of error, especially since I now mostly use Edge when I feel obligated to use a Windows browser. Which is a long way round to say it's up to you!

Comment: Alright well thank you all for your help, maybe google will fix this eventually

Comment: @JCTechie: maybe, but you should consider the possibility that {something} is injecting javascript into your pages. It could be adblock breaking something as well. IMO adblock is worth a little headache.

Comment: @Yorik I agree :)